# problem passing dynamic array via function c

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I have this kind of code

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} Test;

Test* getTest(int *length) {
    Test *toReturn = malloc(sizeof(Test));
    // Some operations with realloc
    return toReturn;
}

void printTest(Test *arrTest, int length) {
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        // Some operations
    }
}

int main() {
    int testlength = 0;
    Test *myTest = getTest(&testlength);
    printTest(myTest, testLength) // Gives random numbers
}
```

Don't know why it gives random numbers, when I'm in the main tho (the whole code) it does not give these kinds of errors

Comment: Fyi, you never change the value of the `int` pointed to by `length` in `getTest`. Nor do you show us any determinate values being set in `getTest` either, nor how you 'print' those values. Post *real* code that replicates the *real* problem please. The posted could would 'print' *nothing*; not random numbers. This "kind" of code isn't good enough if you want a real answer and not pure speculation and wags (wild-ass guesses).

Answer (score 0):

Made minor changes to the code, see below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} Test;

Test* getTest(int *length) {
    Test *toReturn = (Test *)malloc(sizeof(Test));
    // Some operations with realloc
    return toReturn;
}

void printTest(Test *arrTest, int length) {
    printf("%d ", length);
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        // Some operations
    }
}

int main() {
    int tlen = 0;
    Test *myTest = getTest(&tlen);
    printTest(myTest, tlen); // Gives random numbers
    printf("....Exit....");
    return 0;
}
```